# A better dashboard dictionary widget

Tags: dashboard-widget

I find the default dictionary dashboard widget on my MacBook Pro to be very annoying. One, you type in a misspelled word and it says, ""x" could not be found" instead of being helpful and offering alternative spellings. Two, I can't copy and paste from it.

Anyone know of a better one? Or maybe I should just use google?

Thanks.

Comment: The service's provided by the Dictionary application. You can either use it instead of the widget, or use Spotlight directly to search inside the Dictionary.

Comment: @zneak - You're right. Spotlight is the way to go. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use the Dictionary application itself? Does it have to be a widget? The Dictionary application has smart lookup and more tools than the widget.

Comment: Doh! I guess I should have looked through the apps. ;)

Comment: widgets are easier to use.  they're just a swipe away